# Programmatically render inclusion tag in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

Django provides the [`render(…)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut function which essentially takes a template name and a context and returns an instance of [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse) containing the rendered template string.

Is there an official way to do the same thing with an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)? That is, instead of supplying a template name I would like to supply the name of an inclusion tag that then gets rendered with its own context (i.e. what the tag function returns) plus an optional additional context. For example, let's consider the following tag:

```
# myapp/templatetags/myapp.py

@register.inclusion_tag('myapp/mytemplate.html')
def my_inclusion_tag(some_paramter):
    return {
        'some_parameter': some_parameter
    }
```

Then I would like to be able to do something like

```
http_response = render_tag(request, 'myapp.my_inclusion_tag', {'additional_context': value})
```

where the entire context would be `{'some_parameter': some_parameter, 'additional_context': value}`.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone encounters a similar problem, this is the solution I came up with:

```
from django.template import Template, Context

# "micro template" containing the inclusion tag
template_string = f"{{% load myapp %}}{{% my_inclusion_tag %}}"
template_context = {'key1': 'value1', …}
html = Template(template_string).render(Context(template_context))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `loader` to retrieve the template and render it with a context from your templatetag function:

```py
from django.template import loader
from myapp.templatetags.myapp import my_inclusion_tag

context = my_incluseion_tag("some_value")
loader.get_template("myapp/mytemplate.html").render(context)  # rendered template as str
```